# Experience Editor Server Error 8.1

Tags: experience-editor

I am trying to use Experience Editor but it keeps throwing server error in the ribbon:

[image]

I can see the page loads under the bar and progress indicator keeps going on. Here is the error in detail:

[image]

I have tried removing the Control from cshtml file which produces the following result:

[image]

But the progress indicator keeps going on. Has anyone else come across this before or can point me in the right direction :)

Thanks

Sitecore Version: 8.1 (rev. 160519)

Stack Trace is follows:

> [InvalidOperationException: Icon and label request in null or empty.] 
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.LargeDropDownButton.LargeDropDownButton.InitializeAttributes(RenderingParametersResolver
>   renderingParametersResolver) +589
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonIconButtonBase..ctor(RenderingParametersResolver
>   parametersResolver) +23
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.LargeDropDownButton.ControlsExtension.LargeDropDownButton(Controls
>   controls, Rendering rendering) +100
>   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_LargeDropDownButton_LargeDropDownButton_cshtml.Execute()
>   in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot-----\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\LargeDropDownButton\LargeDropDownButton.cshtml:4
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +137    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/LargeDropDownButton/LargeDropDownButton.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1
>   source, Action`1 action) +191
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.RenderItem(TextWriter
>   output, Item item) +265
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +157    Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +127
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.Chunk.Chunk.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +250    Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +127
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.Chunk.ControlsExtension.Chunk(Controls
>   controls, Rendering rendering) +131
>   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_Chunk_Chunk_cshtml.Execute()
>   in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot-----\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\Chunk\Chunk.cshtml:4
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +137    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/Chunk/Chunk.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1
>   source, Action`1 action) +191
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.RenderItem(TextWriter
>   output, Item item) +265
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +157    Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +127
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.Strip.Strip.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +313    Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +127
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.Strip.ControlsExtension.Strip(Controls
>   controls, Rendering rendering) +220
>   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_Strip_Strip_cshtml.Execute()
>   in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot-----\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\Strip\Strip.cshtml:4
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +137    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/Strip/Strip.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1
>   source, Action`1 action) +191
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.RenderItem(TextWriter
>   output, Item item) +265
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +157    Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +127
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.Ribbon.Ribbon.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +198    Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +127
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.Ribbon.ControlsExtension.Ribbon(Controls
>   controls, Rendering rendering) +220
>   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_Ribbon_Ribbon_cshtml.Execute()
>   in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot----\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\Ribbon\Ribbon.cshtml:4
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +137    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/Ribbon/Ribbon.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String
>   placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +216
>   (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String
>   placeholderName) +259
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.PageEditBar.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +265    Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +127
>   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.ControlsExtension.PageEditBar(Controls
>   controls, Rendering rendering, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper) +139
>   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_ExperienceEditor_PageEditbar_PageEditBar_cshtml.Execute()
>   in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot-----\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditBar.cshtml:4
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +137    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/PageEditbar/PageEditBar.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String
>   placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +216
>   (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String
>   placeholderName) +259
>   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute()
>   in
>   c:\inetpub\wwwroot-----\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Speak\Layouts\Layouts\Speak-Layout.cshtml:28
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +253
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +137    Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +343
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view:
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml'
>   (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc'). ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +826 
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +30
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +75    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +184
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +302
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +375    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +90
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +833
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +710

Comment: Are you making use of other databases apart from web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding this issue I requested the support patch from Sitecore and they replied say that this will not apply in this instance. Doing some more investigation I did figure out that previously I tried to upgrade 8.1 to 8.2 and due to facing some errors I rolled it back but I think the database wasn't reverted hence causing the error. I restored the database from 8.1 and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You may need to request the patch `Sitecore.Support.98798` from Sitecore Support.

The issue is due to the fact that the `web` database has been hardcoded in the Sitecore dll.

More info is found at the following link: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/3979

Comment: Thanks Hishaam, I have requested the patch with Sitecore. Will update here as things progress :)