# Experience Editor Ribbon 'siteName' error

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, paas

I have deployed a simple Sitecore 9 website in Azure PaaS. There's nothing so special about the code as it is only a newsletter sign up with Personalization. It works well, I can personalized my vistors, trigger a goal and view it in the Sitecore back-end through Experience Profile and Analytics. Everything is working smoothly as i expected. Until .. I opened my Experience Editor which throws the error below in the ribbon section.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
siteName
Description: An unhandled exception occurred. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: siteName

Source Error: 


Line 2:  @using Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickbarButton
Line 3:  @model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
Line 4:  @Html.Sitecore().Controls().QuickbarButton(Model.Rendering)

Source File: d:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\QuickbarButton\QuickbarButton.cshtml    Line: 4 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: siteName]
   Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetCookieValue(String siteName, String key, String defaultValue) +155
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Contexts.ItemContext.get_WebEditMode() +73
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.AddRendering.CanAddRendering.GetControlState() +87
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.ExecuteProcessComponentState(Object requestObject, T context) +247
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.GetProcessComponentState() +312
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonButtonBase.PreRender() +230
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.RibbonIconButtonBase.PreRender() +24
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +37
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickbarButton.ControlsExtension.QuickbarButton(Controls controls, Rendering rendering) +126
   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_QuickbarButton_QuickbarButton_cshtml.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\QuickbarButton\QuickbarButton.cshtml:4
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +257

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/QuickbarButton/QuickbarButton.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +729
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action) +190
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.RenderItem(TextWriter output, Item item) +270
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.Common.ItemRenderers.ItemRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +143
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +126
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickBar.QuickBar.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter output) +233
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +126
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Controls.QuickBar.ControlsExtension.QuickBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering) +126
   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_Speak_Ribbon_Controls_QuickBar_QuickBar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\Speak\Ribbon\Controls\QuickBar\QuickBar.cshtml:4
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +257

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/Speak/Ribbon/Controls/QuickBar/QuickBar.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +729
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +183
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +258
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.PageEditBar.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +231
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render() +126
   Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.ControlsExtension.PageEditBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper) +133
   ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_ExperienceEditor_PageEditbar_PageEditBar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditBar.cshtml:4
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +257

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/PageEditbar/PageEditBar.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +729
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +183
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +258
   ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute() +2011
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +122
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +136
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +257

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +729
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +73
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +331
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +375
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +776
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +776
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2558.0
```

[image]

I saw this article from the community Sitecore but really not sure if why I encountered it at the first place. https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/3979#pi214filter=all&pi214scroll=false

Any ideas?

Update-1:
I found a similar issue in the stackoverflow. [Experience Editor Server Error 8.1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/experience-editor-server-error-8-1), but seems that is only for sitecore 8

Answer (score 4):

I've provisioned another sitecore paas site, compared bin folder, sitecore folder, sitecore modules folder and app_config. All perfectly fine. And the least changes you've expect that will cause problem bite you back.

In my **PROJECTABC.Website.config**. I've to update some settings

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>

    <events>
      <event name="publish:end">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site hint="projectabc">projectabc</site>
          </sites>
        </handler>
      </event>
      <event name="publish:end:remote">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site hint="projectabc">projectabc</site>
          </sites>
        </handler>
      </event>
    </events>
    <sites>
   <site name="projectabc" patch:after="site[@name='modules_website']"
            enableTracking="true" 
            virtualFolder="/" 
            physicalFolder="/" 
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/Service/PROJECTABC" 
            startItem="home" 
            language="en" 
            database="master" 
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true" 
            cacheHtml="true" 
            htmlCacheSize="50MB" 
            registryCacheSize="0"
            viewStateCacheSize="0" 
            xslCacheSize="25MB" 
            filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" 
            enablePreview="true" 
            enableWebEdit="true" 
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false" 
            cacheRenderingParameters="true" 
            renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" 
            enableItemLanguageFallback="false"
            enableFieldLanguageFallback="false" 
            itemwebapi.mode="Off" 
            itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" 
            itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" />
    </sites>
    <cacheSizes>
      <sites>
        <projectabc>
          <html>50MB</html>
          <registry>0</registry>
          <viewState>0</viewState>
          <xsl>25MB</xsl>
        </projectabc>
      </sites>
    </cacheSizes>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Preview.DefaultSite">
        <patch:attribute name="value" value="projectabc" />
      </setting>
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Just to clarify Marvin's answer, in my case this was caused by `Preview.DefaultSite` being set to a value that didn't have a matching `<site>` entry.

Comment: This can also happen if you decide to delete the default site "website" (for instance, if all your sites are defined within SXA).