# Editable sections disappear Experience Editor

Tags: sxa

I am using SXA 1.8, as Administrator adding a default Page (using the `MVCLayout`) and switch to the Experience Editor. When the EE loads it shortly shows editable sections, but once completed loaded the editable section disappears.

The edit button in the ribbon is greyed-out as well.

In the Content Editor I can add a Rendering (e.g. Title) without problems.

Screen when loading Experience Editor:
[image]

Screen when loading is completed:
[image]

Any suggestions what may cause this?

Comment: What theme do you use? Have you changed css? Can you see "Add here" buttons if you hit "Add Component" button in the ribbon?

Comment: Any of the answers here help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626544/sitecore-mvc-ensure-empty-placeholder-is-selectable-in-experience-editor/39335110 ?

Comment: Seems not be to CSS related, the `<div>` containing the editable sections disappears from the DOM after the page completes.

Comment: Check that you don't have a site in your `<sites>` config file that conflicts with an SXA site. I have had that before and it produced similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by removing `Preview.DefaultSite` from:

```
<settings>
   <setting name="Preview.DefaultSite">
       <patch:attribute name="value" value="..." />
   </setting>
</settings>
```

as mentioned in [Experience Editor Ribbon 'siteName' error](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10439/experience-editor-ribbon-sitename-error#comment22798_10445)